# Saving android specific button sound

Tags: android

I have a soundboard and I am trying to save sounds as a ringtone or notification but it is saving the same sound each time which I think is being pulled from " here can anyone shed some light? Thinking it needs to change R.raw.sound1 so it pulls in the sound of which ever button is clicked to bring up the context menu.

I've added the loop and integrs code which makes the buttons work just in case.

EDIT FULL CODE - Error: selectedSoundId cannot be resolved
:-   for each three bits of code that say selectedSoundId

Not sure if I have done this bit:
Where and how do I add this?

The "int selectedSoundId" should be declared as a class field, to make it accessible in every class method.

```
public class Soundboard extends Activity {
 private SoundManager mSoundManager;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
int selectedSoundId;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.soundboard);

    final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    final Resources res = getResources();

    //just keep them in the same order, e.g. button01 is tied to backtoyou
    final int[] buttonIds = { R.id.backdoors etc};
    final int[] soundIds = { R.raw.back_doors etc };

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //find the index that matches the button's ID, and then reset
            //the MediaPlayer instance, set the data source to the corresponding
            //sound effect, prepare it, and start it playing.
            for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
                if(v.getId() == buttonIds[i]) {
                    selectedSoundId = soundIds[i];
                    AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(soundIds[i]);
                    player.reset();
                    try {
                        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        player.prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    player.start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    //set the same listener for every button ID, no need
    //to keep a reference to every button
    for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
        Button soundButton = (Button)findViewById(buttonIds[i]);
        registerForContextMenu(soundButton);
        soundButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
 super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
 menu.setHeaderTitle("Save as...");
 menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Ringtone");
 menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Notification");
}
@Override   
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
 if(item.getTitle()=="Ringtone"){function1(item.getItemId());}   
  else if(item.getTitle()=="Notification"){function2(item.getItemId());}  
  else {return false;}
 return true; 
}

public void function1(int id){  

    if 
     (savering(selectedSoundId)){   
      // Code if successful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Ringtone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }           
     else           
     { 
      // Code if unsuccessful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
    }
    public void function2(int id){   
     if 
     (savenot(selectedSoundId)){   
      // Code if successful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }           
     else           
     { 
      // Code if unsuccessful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }
    }

     //Save into Ring tone Folder

public boolean savering(int ressound){
 byte[] buffer=null;
 InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
 int size=50; 

 try {
   size = fIn.available();   
   buffer = new byte[size];   
   fIn.read(buffer);   
   fIn.close(); 
 } catch (IOException e) { 
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;      } 

 String path="/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/";

 String filename="ohhh"+".ogg";


 boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();   
 if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}   

 FileOutputStream save;
 try { 
  save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);   
  save.write(buffer);   
  save.flush();   
  save.close();   
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;  
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;
 }
 sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,   Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename))); 

 File k = new File(path, filename);   
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Ohhh Ringtone");   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "weee");   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);    

 //Insert it into the database
 this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);

 return true; 
}

     //Save in Notification Folder

public boolean savenot(int ressound){
 byte[] buffer=null;
 InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
 int size=0; 

 try {
   size = fIn.available();   
   buffer = new byte[size];   
   fIn.read(buffer);   
   fIn.close(); 
 } catch (IOException e) { 
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;      } 

 String path="/sdcard/media/audio/notifications/";

 String filename="ohhh"+".ogg";

 boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();   
 if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}   

 FileOutputStream save;
 try { 
  save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);   
  save.write(buffer);   
  save.flush();   
  save.close();   
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;  
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;
 }
 sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,   Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename))); 

 File k = new File(path, filename);   
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Ohhh Notification");   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "weee");   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);    

 //Insert it into the database
 this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);

 return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you are replacing the content of

```
R.raw.sound1
```

which you are passing as an argument, thus, as I can observe in your code, you are saving the same sound every time you call the saving methods.

EDIT:

1. Create int variable which will hold the info about last selected sound:

   int selectedSoundId;
2. In onClickListener set the selectedSoundId to sound id connected with current button:

   if(v.getId() == buttonIds[i]) {
   selectedSoundId = soundIds[i];
   //rest of the code
   }
3. Pass the selectedSoundId to savering and savenot methods:

   savering(selectedSoundId);
   savenot(selectedSoundId);

Hope this helps.

EDIT 2: I'm pasting your code with my corrections.

Ad.2. This is the part when you need to save the info about current sound id.

```
final int[] buttonIds = { R.raw.sound1 "etc all buttons here"};
    final int[] soundIds = {R.raw.sound1 "etc all sounds here"};

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //find the index that matches the button's ID, and then reset
            //the MediaPlayer instance, set the data source to the corresponding
            //sound effect, prepare it, and start it playing.
            for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
                if(v.getId() == buttonIds[i]) {
                    selectedSoundId = soundIds[i];
                    AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(soundIds[i]);
                    player.reset();
                    try {
                        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        player.prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    player.start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Ad.3. This is the part of calling the savering and savenot methods.

```
if 
 (savering(selectedSoundId)){   
  // Code if successful   
  Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Ringtone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
 }           
 else           
 { 
  // Code if unsuccessful   
  Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }

}
public void function2(int id){   
 if 
 (savenot(selectedSoundId)){   
  // Code if successful   
  Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
 }           
 else           
 { 
  // Code if unsuccessful   
  Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
 }
}
```

Comment: Yes i know that thanks i am wondering if anyone can shine some light on the code i should replace that with so it will save the sound of whichever button is clicked

Comment: Sorry for the messy formatting of the code I provided - the editor is somewhat not doing what I want it to do :) Anyway: i hope this helps you, if not, feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: Hi Deimos that looks like it could work, but as i am a beginer i cant seem to find the correct place the first two lines of code you gave without spitting errors out. I am gusseing the third savering section replaces the current section with this code. Could you possibly point me in teh right direction with the other two thank you so much

Comment: Ok I edited the answer. The "int selectedSoundId" should be declared as a class field, to make it accessible in every class method.

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far i have updated the orignal question for you it is just spitting out errors anywhere selectedSoundId is called selectedSoundId cannot be resolved

Comment: Have you declared the selectedSoundId variable?

Comment: I dont think so what is the code for this and where abouts do i add it. Thanks

Comment: Just before the onCreate method write the declaration:

int selectedSoundId;

Comment: Do you mean above this section? public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.soundboard);

Comment: Ok i have tried like this                                          int selectedSoundId;
@Override                                                              and the opposit way round but if i put it after the override i have to remove the override or i get an error but adding that line removes the errors but when i try to save as ringtone or notification it force closes the app. I hope you can help me out with the final tweaks really need to get it sorted. Ive updated the full code full you to have a look if you can. Thanks

Comment: Do i have to add something to the manifest now i have declared the variable